# How to work with exact size units like inch & mm in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply width to div in inches , but i measure it with ruler then it not exact size & show different-2 size in different-2 screen resolution

So my question is  how to work with exact size units in HTML & CSS
like if apply 2in width to a div then it display exact 2in on every screen resolution

eg-

```css
.a{width: 2in; height: 2in;background-color:#000;}
.b{width: 4cm; height: 4cm;background-color: #f00;}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<br>
<div class="b"></div>
```

thanks in advance for help

Comment: This is not possible. It depends on how many pixels a screen has per inch and thus there alwas is a different pixel amount on different devices.

Comment: did you try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)?. Edit: `* Pixels (px) are relative to the viewing device. For low-dpi devices, 1px is one device pixel (dot) of the display. For printers and high resolution screens 1px implies multiple device pixels.`

Comment: @LiranBo i used the this w3school reference & provide size in in & mm

Comment: so you managed to solve your problem then?

Comment: @Dinesh Are you any closer to solving the problem after six years?